# <body onresize="jsUpdateSize()"> not firing

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I'm currently learning to develop with SharePoint 2013. I have created a custom master page and added a script element, as seen below.

```
    function jsUpdateSize() {
        // Get the dimensions of the viewport
        var width = window.outerWidth;

        if (width >= 1280) {
            document.getElementById('span_title').innerHTML = 'Full Title';
            document.getElementById('span_author').innerHTML = 'Full Author';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('span_title').innerHTML = 'Short Title';
            document.getElementById('span_author').innerHTML = 'Short Author';
        }
    };
```

This is called in the body tag, both onload and onresize.

```
<body onload="jsUpdateSize()" onresize="jsUpdateSize()">
```

The onload call works correctly. If I change my browser width and refresh the page I get the appropriate text. Unfortunately it does not do this whilst re-sizing the browser.

I have also tried adding

```
window.onload = jsUpdateSize;       // When the page first loads
window.onresize = jsUpdateSize;     // When the browser changes size
```

Unfortunately the same result occurred.

I have tested this script in Firefox, Chrome and IE. All produce the same results.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Works for me, Chrome on Linux.

Comment: Place the javascript function in your body tag

Comment: Thanks, but the JavaScript function is already inside the body tag.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gmp24Lap/ I wrapped the code in the head, it works fine. Wrapping it in the body works too. P.S. I changed the value to 900 to test

Comment: I'm starting to suspect this is some SharePoint master page peculiarity...